# How to cast a ReadOnlyCollection<T> to T[]?

Tags: c#

I have a class with a ReadOnlyCollection property.  I need to convert that ReadOnlyCollection into a int[].  How can this be done?  Is it possible to do this without iterating over the collection?

Comment: What version of C# are you using? There's a million ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Presumably, the collection will be iterated at some point - maybe that code can accept an IEnumerable<T> instead of T[].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not possible to convert a ReadOnlyCollection to an array without iterating it. That would turn the collection to a writable collection, breaking the contract of being read-only.

There are different ways of iterating the collection that spares you of writing the loop yourself, for example using the CopyTo method

```
int[] collection = new int[theObject.TheProperty.Count];
theObject.TheProperty.CopyTo(collection, 0);
```

Or the extension method ToArray:

```
int[] collection = theObject.TheProperty.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 15):

Sure using a LINQ extension method `myReadOnlyCollection.ToArray()`.

Comment: Strictly speaking you're still iterating over the collection - but then again, you can't **not** iterate to do this.

Comment: Yeah that's right it just gets nicely wraped by the framework. :)

Answer (score 6):

There aren't any ways without iterating.  There is a built-in method to do this though:

```
T[] myArray;
myCollection.CopyTo(myArray, 0);
```

or using Linq:

```
var myArray = myCollection.ToArray();
```

Comment: `CopyTo()` takes the start index not total count as the second param...sorry, couldn't fix this while SO was down, updated now.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the later versions of the .NET framework `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.  `IEnumerable<T>` has an extension method `ToArray()`.  So you'd use that extension method like so...

```
var readOnly = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5});
var myArray = readOnly.ToArray();
```